# How to give dynamic query parameter in <script> src?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, src

I am building a simple asp.net application and in my `aspx` page I want to reference a script with dynamic query parameter.

**For example:**

```
<script src="../javascript/script.js?v=#var#" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the above code script path can have different query parameter in place of `#var#`.

I have also tried following code to get the parameter value from code behind.

```
<script src="../javascript/script.js?v=<%# myVar %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but, here `<%# myVar %>` returns blank value. If I use `=` instead of `#` then it works perfectly if I add the script reference at the bottom of the page.

But, it only works if I reference the script at the bottom of page. otherwise it will throw the error.

```
"The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. `<%= %>`)."
```

Now, my question is, **"Is there any other way to do the same?"**

Comment: try `<script src="../javascript/script.js?v=<%= myVar %>" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: @VDWWD yes I know as I have said in my question it will work but it will throw error if I use it at the top of the page with the script reference.

Comment: Note the `%>` instead of `#>` at the end of `myVar`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using `ASP.net` not `MVC`. I have tried this with `ASP.net` and done this by code behind approach you can create your `script` tag by code behind like below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string jScriptValidator;
    jScriptValidator = "<script type='text/javascript' src='../javascript/script.js?v=#123'></script>"; // your dynamic script tag with dynamic parameter         
    Page.RegisterStartupScript("key", jScriptValidator);
    }
```

and result is follows:

[image]

Hope it helps you.